# Как можно задать дефолтный параметр -j8 для make?

Tags: linux, makefile, archlinux

Я использую pamac для того, чтобы удобнее было пользоваться репозиторием AUR. Но проблема в том, что на стадии компиляции используется лишь 1 ядро, а хотелось чтобы все. Есть ли какая либо переменная окружения для этого или какой недь хак?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот [здесь](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=91592) говорят, что помогает добавить в файл `/etc/makepkg.conf` строку:

```
MAKEFLAGS="-j8"
```

Comment: Очень похоже, ведь в этом файле строка с -j2 была закомментирована. Спасибо.